# twitter oauth authorization on android , without open browser .. how to?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm creating an android app that will share content through twitter and i'm facing some trouble with twitter oauth . I'm using twitter4j . I've seen some tutorials but all of than open the browser for autorization. Is there some way to autorize  without open the browser?
some sort of : dialog pops up and the user type his id and password , and the api autorize it without open the browser , webView , etc...

Comment: There is an example of what you need in my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013689/twitter-api-returns-invalid-callback-cannot-authorize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the twitter page, but you can do it in a `WebView`.  You don't need to pass it off to the Browser.

Comment: Could you give me some sample codes to load twitter page (for authentication) in webview?