# get authentication - without using Twitter browser page

Tags: java, android, twitter

I try to create Twitter client and now I deal with authorization via OAuth protocol. I have created "Sign In" button to come in WebView and load twitter authorization URL, that's work. When the authorization is accepted successfully and Twitter service redirect me to my callback

But, can I get authentication - without using Twitter browser page?

Comment: solution to my problem [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683084/twitter-oauth-authorization-on-android-without-open-browser-how-to